# Unit test UI methods

Tags: unit-testing, user-interface

My question is simple (and probably well known among more experienced developers):

How do I unit test this method (I know, not a method, because it's not in a class, but lets assume it is)?

```
void drawRegularPolygon(int numberOfPoint, Point centerPoint, double radius)
{
    double angleDelta = 2 * PI / numberOfPoint;

    Point firstPoint = new Point(centerPoint.x + radius, centerPoint.y);

    for (int i = 1; i < numberOfPoint; i++) {
        double angle = angleDelta * i;
        Point secondPoint = new Point(centerPoint.x + radius * cos(angle), centerPoint.y + radius * sin(angle));

        DrawLine(firstPoint, secondPoint);

        firstPoint = secondPoint;
    }
}
```

I accept answer saying "you should refactor this to look like `this` before even considering testing it".

EDIT 1:
I just found a bug in my code, but I left it there to have an idea of how a unit test should catch it.

EDIT 2:
I also thought of another solution

```
Array<Line> regularPolygonLines(int numberOfPoint, Point centerPoint, double radius)
{
    Array<Line> lines = new Array<Line>;

    double angleDelta = 2 * PI / numberOfPoint;

    Point firstPoint = new Point(centerPoint.x + radius, centerPoint.y);

    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPoint; i++) {
        double angle = angleDelta * i;
        Point secondPoint = new Point(centerPoint.x + radius * cos(angle), centerPoint.y + radius * sin(angle));

        lines.add(new Line(firstPoint, secondPoint));

        firstPoint = secondPoint;
    }

    return lines;
}

void drawRegularPolygon(int numberOfPoint, Point centerPoint, double radius)
{
    Array<Line> lines = regularPolygonLines(numberOfPoint, centerPoint, radius);

    for (Line line in lines) {
        DrawLine(line.firstPoint, line.secondPoint);
    }
}
```

And in this one, the `regularPolygonLines` method could be tested, but the `drawRegularPolygon` could not.

Comment: You were on the right track when you pulled out the *calculation* and isolating the *rendering*. Indeed the calculation can be tested and you can think of it as the "business rules" for the UI. It also helps with SRP and clarity.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways of looking at this, and in reverse order of usefulness,

**You don't test UIs**

Normally when you are developing an application, the bit that is important is the application functionality, as a result its often far better to test that it calculated the correct result, and not that it presented it in Green text. Worse as your application develops and you move from one UI look to another then whole test suites are suddenly broken simply because you moved a button from bottom-right to bottom-left, or changed your Green text to Yellow text. I have worked in organisations where the testing is instead performed one level down, (the View Model in and MVVM application for example) so that instead of testing *what happens if I click this button* we test *what happens if I run this command*.

However given that are developing a piece of code that actually draws something, then you do probably want to test this.

**You can use a UI test framework**

There have been quite a few test framework (extensions?) such as [NUnitForms](http://nunitforms.sourceforge.net/), [White](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/john_daddamio/archive/2008/04/04/testing-wpf-applications-with-the-white-ui-test-framework.aspx) and more recently [WipFlash](http://codebetter.com/benhall/2010/03/16/testing-a-wpf-ui-using-ruby-cucumber-and-wipflash-dll/). These can work in several ways, providing the equivalent of drivers enabling you to find elements, interact with them, or at a lower level,  move the mouse and click elements directly. Some of these even provide screen comparison functionality to enable you to compare what has been rendered against a previous stored good render.

**You Mock/Fake the dependencies and see if they produce what you expect**
*(This is probably the answer you are looking for)*

You can alternatively use a more BDD like approach and use a set of examples to verify the known examples. Start with the simplest case, a 2-sided shape or a *line*. This we can work out (in our heads) that if we draw it with a 50 radius around the point 100,100 then we should end up with a line from 100,150 to 100,50 and another from 100,50 to 100,150 (or vice versa). So what we now need is some way of getting the points that `DrawLine(...)` would draw.

As such you inject a class to handle the drawing and facilitate our ability to replace it with something else that Mocks the functionality so we can catch its actions.

```
public interface IDrawStuff
{
   void DrawLine(Point start, Point end);
}

public class RealDrawStuff : IDrawStuff
{

  public void DrawLine(Point start, Point end)
  {
    // call the frameworks draw line functionality
  }
}
```

Now we can simply inject our Mock functionality, this can be done with Mocking frameworks such as [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) but so you understand this more simply, lets create our own for now. In this case we simply remember the points that your code calculated

```
public class MockDrawStuff : IDrawStuff
{
 private List<Tuple<Point,Point>> drawnPoints = new List<Tuple<Point,Point>>();
 public class DrawLine(Point start, Point end)
 {
    drawnPoints.Add(new Tuple<Point,Point>(start,end));
 }

 public void Verify(Tuple<Point,Point>[] expectedPoints)
 {
    foreach(var i=0; i<expectedPoints.Count; i++)
    {
       var expected = expectedPoints[i];
       var actual = drawnPoints[i];
       if (actual.Item1.X != expected.Item1.X
         || actual.Item1.Y != expected.Item1.Y
         || actual.Item2.X != expected.Item2.X
         || actual.Item2.Y != expected.Item2.Y)
       {
            throw new Exception("Fail: {0} != {1}",expected, actual); 
            //Probably wants more detail, but you get the idea
        }
    }
}
```

And your code becomes

```
public class MyPolygonRenderer
{
 private IDrawStuff renderer;

  public MyPolygonRender(IDrawStuff renderer)
  {
     this.renderer = renderer;
  }

  void drawRegularPolygon(int numberOfPoint, Point centerPoint, double radius)
 {
double angleDelta = 2 * PI / numberOfPoint;

Point firstPoint = new Point(centerPoint.x + radius, centerPoint.y);

for (int i = 1; i < numberOfPoint; i++) {
    double angle = angleDelta * i;
    Point secondPoint = new Point(centerPoint.x + radius * cos(angle), centerPoint.y + radius * sin(angle));

    // Code change here
    renderer.DrawLine(firstPoint, secondPoint);

    firstPoint = secondPoint;
  }
 }
}
```

Which means that we can now finally write our test as

```
[TestFixure] //Assuming NUnit
public class MyPolygonRendererTests
{
   [Test]
   public void ShouldDrawASimpleLine()
   {
      //Given
      var mockDrawStuff = new MockDrawStuff();         
      var polygonRenderer = new MyPolygonRenderer(mockDrawStuff);

     //When
     polygonRenderer.drawRegularPolygon(2, new Point(100,100),50);

    //Then
    mockDrawStuff.Verify(new [] {
      new Tuple<POint,Point>(new Point (100,150), new Point(100,50)),
      new Tuple<POint,Point>(new Point (100,50), new Point(100,150))
     });
   }
}
```

And then you can build up other tests by working out examples for 3 points, 4 points etc.

Comment: I thought of doing that last one, but what if I don't want who ever uses my drawRegularPolygon method to know about the actual rendering? So I can't have the IDrawStuff renderer as something public in the constructor.

Comment: Also, do you think using your first approach (don't test UI) with my EDIT 2 would be better?

Comment: Use a different injection strategy then. You could simply use *factory methods*, i.e. make the constructor with parameters `protected` then have `public MyPologonRenderer() : this(new RealDrawStuff()) {}` and a `public static MyPolygonRenderer ForTesting(IDrawStuff testDrawStuff) { return new MyPolygonRenderer(testDrawStuff)}` or *Property injection* e.g. you expose an internal property that lets you set the `IDrawStuff` and then mark your code with `[InternalsVisibleTo("MyPolygonRendererTestsAssembly")`.

Comment: Your edit 2 is still testable, you just need to work out what kind of test you want. If you want to write a *pure* Unit test then you would need to mock out the call to `regularPolygonLines(...)`. Otherwise you are starting to integrate these methods together so you could consider this an integration test and test them together *(although personally I would still consider this a unit test as you are still in the same class)*.

Comment: Yeah, I'd say its a unit test because it is in the same class too. But about the dependency injection, creating a property just to make it visible only for a test class seems wrong. Is there a better way?

Comment: Well that is why it is `internal` so it is less visible, but you can always just turn it into a method call instead.